# Styling suggestion documentation for Monaco Editor

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm trying to get a look and feel similar to IntelliJ where the autocompletion has two columns. The first one contains the function signature and the second one the return type. In the documentation popup the first section shows the full function signature, then a visual separator and finally the function documentation follwed by the parameter documentation in a table style.

[image: intellij]

It seems that the monaco editor displays completion items like the following. The `label` is in the left column and the `detail` in the right column in the suggestion popup. But then it uses the content of the `detail` in the documentation popup. Can I disable this somehow?

The next issue is, that I would like to use HTML in the Markdown string for the completion item `documentation`, but HTML gets escaped. The reason I want to use HTML is to be able to get a similar parameter styling like IntelliJ.

[image]

Is that somehow possible?